# Check if a user is typing using App Engine XMPP

Tags: google-app-engine, xmpp

The XMPP service in GAE is great and all, but I'm really interested in when a user opens up a window to send a message, or when he/she starts typing. I think XMPP supports this, because Pidgin does this, as does Google Talk, so why not the XMPP/GAE service?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately App Engine doesn't pass in [Chat State notifications](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0085.html) to the application, so you won't be able to receive notifications of a user typing a message ("composing") until they actually send it.